# Spring Boot falls back to system Locale if Accepte-Language header was not submitted even if fallback-to-system-locale is set to false

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot web application and noticed a problem with the Accept-Language header and the "default" language Spring Boot defines.

Assume we have an application supporting English (messages.properties), French (messages_fr.properties) and German (messages_de.properties). If the request sends the header "Accept-Language" containing fr or de, the corresponding message_xx.properties file should be used. For all other languages, the default language English provided by the messages.properties should be used.

This works, as long as the Accept-Language header was submitted.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.jvisions.games</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMessageGames</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMessageGames</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.propperties**

```properties
#1. Core properties -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Whether to fall back to the system Locale if no files for a specific Locale have been found.
# If this is turned off, the only fallback will be the default file (e.g. "messages.properties" for basename "messages").
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false


# 9. Web properties -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Spring MVC view prefix.
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
# Spring MVC view suffix.
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


# 11. Server properties ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Server HTTP port.
server.port=8080
```

**messages.properties**

```properties
text.message=Default message (English message)
```

**messages_de.properties**

```properties
text.message=Deutsche Meldung (German message)
```

**messages_fr.properties**

```properties
text.message=Message en fran\u00e7ais (French message)
```

**MessageController.java**

```java
package de.jvisions.games;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MessageController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String runGame() {
        return "message";
    }
}
```

**message.jsp**

```jsp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spring Message 01</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Spring Message 01</h1>
        <spring:message code="text.message"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Test Cases**

1. Set the "Accept-Language" header to German [de] only, call this page, the result is `Deutsche Meldung (German message)`.
2. Set the "Accept-Language" header to French [fr] only, call the page, the result is `Message en français (French message)`
3. Set the "Accept-Language" header to any other language than German [de] or French [fr], call this page, the result should be `Default message (English message)`
4. Remove all languages from the "Accept-Language" setting, call this page.
   Now the Locale of your web server takes account!

   - If the server Locale is Locale.GERMAN. The messages_de.properties file will be used.
   - If the server Locale is Locale.FRENCH. The messages_fr.properties file will be used.
   - If the server Locale is set to any onther language, the messages.properties will be used.

But I expected the same behavior as requesting a language, were no message file exists, instead of the server dependent one. Especially if the `spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false` is set.

So. How to fall back to the messages.properties, if the Accept-Language header was not submitted as if the Accept-Language header was set to a 'not supported' language?
Or, should I expect, the Accept-Language header will always set? (Sounds weird to me.)